# How to track "conversions" between subdomains in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 subdomains with the same GA counter installed: `www.mydomain` and `blog.mydomain` - that's an e-commerce site and related blog. I have added a bunch of links to `blog` on various pages on my `www` domain. I would like to know on what pages what links to blog are clicked. In other words, I want top 10 pages on `www` subdomain which generated most of the traffic to `blog`, and report showing 10 most popular `blog` links which were clicked on `www` domain. Essentially, I need to see how successfully I lead customers to my blog pages from the main website.

I understand I can achieve this with adding event which will track source and destination URL - but i'm not sure if that's the right way to proceed. Both pages (source and destination) live on the my domain, so I believe there should be a more natural way to track what I described above. Is there?

Comment: Are you wanting to swap to one single GA domain that tracks both?

Comment: i already have that - i need to know how to get that report - showing customers who went clicked a link on `www` page to get to `blog` page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, is it merging them together at the moment? or are you not getting any data from the blog page for instance.

Comment: I get all data - i just do not know how to get that final report which will tell me that `blog/page1` was accessed 10 times from `www/page1`, 20 times from `www/page2` etc; `blog/page2` was accessed from .... and so on. Thanks!