# Google analytics conversion tracking across subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, cookie, session

I've got a Drupal site at `example.com`, which leads to an ecommerce site at `ticketing.example.com`. Both sites have our GA code installed, and the cookiedomain for both sites is set to 'auto'. Based on the cookies I'm seeing in my browser settings, the GA cookies seem to be set properly for cross-subdomain tracking.

The issue I'm running into is that the sessions don't seem to be tracking across subdomains. One reason I say this is that `example.com` shows up as a referrer when I view the goal flow for a sale on the `ticketing.example.com`. Another red flag is that in testing, I've used specific UTM parameters to go from a landing page through to a sale, and I've been unable to view these completed goals starting with my known campaign term.

Are there specific configuration settings I should look for to be able to see these conversions attributed properly? Or what other steps should I take in troubleshooting?

There are a few related questions, specifically [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-to-track-conversions-between-subdomains-in-google-analytics) and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84044/how-do-i-properly-set-up-google-analytics-to-track-conversions-that-start-on-my), but none have an accepted answer or enough information to begin troubleshooting.